# Nodes connection problem for Cassandra in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, connection, aws-security-group

Hi I'm creating a cluster in AWS to run Cassandra. 
So far I have created 3 Ec2 instances in the same region but in three different availability zones.

I modified the .yaml in this way:

- For **Ec2-1**: seeds: **Ec2-2** private_ip, listen_address: **Ec2-2** private_ip, broadcast_rpc_address: **Ec2-2** private_ip (with rpc_address:
  0.0.0.0)
- For **Ec2-2** and **Ec2-3** similarly I used the private_ip of **Ec2-3** and **Ec2-1** respectively.

Finally I put all these three instances in the same security group but actually cassandra does not work.

The error in the log file for Ec2-1 is:

*org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to bind to address /172.31.15.109:7000.*

(where 172.31.15.109 is the Ec2-2 private_ip).

This seems to be a problem related with the communication between the nodes but i don't understand why they can't communicate (with a single ping or a telnet using port 22 they sees each other).

Those are the rule I added in the security group both in inbound and outbound: i also added the rule all traffic but nothing change.

[image: security group rules]

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems to be wrong.

Refer the link http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html

The listen_address and rpc_address of a node should IP of the node itself not other node's IP.